# Navigating between Hamburger button UWP application become slow

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, template10

We are building the application using UWP and Template10 and facing an memory leak issue.

When we are navigating to multiple views (using Hamburger button) application is becoming very slow. so we monitored the memory and observed that application's memory is getting increased as we navigate from one page to another.

When application starts, the memory showed in TaksManager is 56 MB. when we navigate to several pages over a period of time, we observed that application memory reaches 600 MB.

Note: We used Exapndo object to bind the data to the grid.
Please let us know is there any way to dispose/clear  Page objects in UWP/Template10.

Thanks

Comment: Please share sample code or a project for us to be able to create a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AdityaSharma siad, please share a [mcve] that can reproduce your issue. With current info, it'a hard to say where your issue is.

Comment: It's hard to guess unless you provide more info. For instance, are you using view-model? do you use x:Bind, do you use a lot of image binding? For memory consumption to escalate from 50MB to 600MB something is seriously wrong but fellow developers here on SO would have no clue how you're approaching the design problem.

Comment: Consider [this](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/issues/1403) template10 issue